# Postgresql: using psql to run deployment scripts in powershell

Tags: powershell, psql

I'm trying to execute some sql commands using psql from powershell

```
   $env:PGPASSWORD = "superuser";

   psql  -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d  "DB_DEV"  -f ".../schema.sql"
```

this works fine on my machine but when i gave it to execute on my colleagues machine it gives a connect to server dialog like the one in image. I have checked pgpass file and there is no difference. Is it something do with signing scripts or execution policy for powershell current execution policy on both machines is "remotesigned".

The only difference is he has installed postgresql on different drive, but i have added it to PATH variable so it should not be a problem

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: That is **not** a prompt from `psql`. It seems like on the other computer the script runs pgAdmin. Unrelated: if you set the environment variable `PGPASSWORD` you don't really need pgpass any more

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name U r right in windows default program for .sql file is set to pgAdmin that is why its opening connect server prompt. but powershell on that machine is not event executing other commands in my .ps1 file like change current working directory."Set-Location "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\";"